# Manually pre-compile xml layout files and use them

Tags: android

Is it possible to manually pre-compile a layout file, put it in a jar and use it?
if possible how ?

I'll explain:
When using a apk packaging, the build process pre compile xml resources, for runtime optimization.
Let's say, for example, I want to load xml files from a server, and load them to ui.
I need to pre-compile them, and I prefer doing it on server side with the android sdk.

Comment: XAML? Are you sure? What have you tried yet?

Comment: please explain your question, it's not understandable

Comment: did my best hope it's enought.

Comment: Hi, have you found an answer to your question? if you do, could you please post it here? I'm looking for the exact same thing. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

**try this:**

1. put your xml file into your resource folder (for example into res/xml)
2. run your project
3. go to bin folder of your project
4. open youapplication.apk as zip-archive
5. go to res/xml folder of your archive
6. extract already compiled xml from that folder
7. use extracted xml as your complied xml file

Comment: Please, where is the bin folder located now in latest version of Android studio because i can't find any...